# Running Oracle database as a docker container in Kubernetes

Tags: oracle, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am actually new to the Kubernetes and i am in the process of learning Kubernetes by installing minikube in my local desktop. May be i am unaware of this, but i wanted to ask this question to the experts

Here is what i am trying to achieve. I have 3 docker containers created in my local environment. 2 java web based application(app1, app2) docker containers and 1 oracle database container (oracleDB).

app1 application depends on the oracleDB. I installed minikube in my local environment for trying out Kubernetes.

I was able to deploy my applications app1, app2 and oracleDB in the minikube and bring up the applications and also able to access those application using the url like  http://local_minikube_ip:31213/app1

After few hours my app was not responding, so i had to restart the minikube. When i restart the minikube, i found out that i lost the database imported into the oracle docker container. I had to re-import the database and also ssh into the app1 and start the app1 and app2 containers.

So i want to know how everyone handles this scenario ? is there anyway i can maintain the data in the oracle database container during the restarts of Kubernetes ?

Can someone help me with this please ?

Answer (score 1):

For data persistence you need to define `Volumes` in your PODs, it is often done in conjunction with `Persistent Volume Clams` and `Persistent Volumes`.

Take a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/ to get a better picture of how to achieve that

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am actually looking at the Volumes concepts in Kubernetes. I thought Volume is same as the Docker, but it is not. As you pointed out, Persistent Volume Claims is what i need i guess. But i need to read the whole documentation on that to confirm.